# FluentD unable to establish connection to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elastic-stack, fluentd, efk

I am trying to setup an FluentD + ECK on my Kubernetes Cluster.

But FluentD is failing to establish connection with ElasticSearch which is on SSL.

**Error log**

```
2022-10-12 04:55:27 +0000 [info]: adding match in @OUTPUT pattern="**" type="elasticsearch"
2022-10-12 04:55:29 +0000 [warn]: #0 Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. EOFError (EOFError)
2022-10-12 04:55:29 +0000 [warn]: #0 Remaining retry: 14. Retry to communicate after 2 second(s).
2022-10-12 04:55:33 +0000 [warn]: #0 Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. EOFError (EOFError)
2022-10-12 04:55:33 +0000 [warn]: #0 Remaining retry: 13. Retry to communicate after 4 second(s).
```

**FluentD output Conf**

```
<label @OUTPUT>
      <match **>
        @type elasticsearch
        host elasticsearch-es-http
        port 9200
        path ""
        user elastic
        password XXXXXXXXX
        ca_path "/etc/ssl/certs/ca.crt"
      </match>
    </label>
```

Mounted the below ElasticSearch secret as cert on fluentd

```
- name: elasticsearch-es-http-certs-public
  secret:
    secretName: elasticsearch-es-http-certs-public

- name: elasticsearch-es-http-certs-public
  mountPath: "/etc/ssl/certs"
```

**elasticsearch-es-http** is the ElasticSearch Service name and the PODs are up and running.

Please guide me on where I went wrong.

Comment: can you also add `kubectl get svc`, whats the service name for elasticsearch? both are in same namespace? also try to disable TLS, `scheme: http`

Comment: Hi Adi,
Yeah , the service name is same as the hostname.
Issue is same even if I change the scheme to http , the elasticsearch is configured with https as per ECK.